# Rails controller initiate others controller create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, associations

I need to make new `Footprint` on every action user makes in database. How can I initiate `Footprint.new()` on other controller also giving automatic statement with it.

For example when User deletes `entity`.

`entity_controller` action `delete` will pass such statement as `"user"+ "{ @user.name }" + "deleted entity "{ @entity.name }"` to `footprint.description`.

Also it should pass current user `id` to `footprint.user_id`

Don't know how to do it!

Answer (score 0):

I was not clear on your question , but what i felt was that you want to delete an `entity` and then wanna pass deleted `entity` name to another `action` which is , in some other `controller` .

```
def delete
  entity = Entity.find(params[:id]
  entity_name = entity.name
  entity.destroy!
  footprint_path(entity_name)
end
```

you can use `path helpers` when you have defined `resources` in your `routes.rb` , which in this case is , `resource "footprint"`

**Update**
To track user's activity you can use [paper_trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) or [Userstamping](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_User_Stamping)

Comment: No, I needed to know how can I track every action by users. When user deletes Entity I wan't to make now Footprint stating witch user deleted witch entity.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need a user activity feed on your application. You can make use of the [Public Activity](https://github.com/chaps-io/public_activity) gem for achieving this functionality. There is also a nice [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/406-public-activity?view=asciicast) about the gem.